# Método correto para gravar em WEB API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Eu fiz um teste usando um método desta forma, teste usando o PostMan é funcionou, queria saber se desta forma eu posso ter algum problema.

no Controller

```
//http://localhost:1608/api/ApiGuiaCidade/cadastrar/cliente/jose/02-02-2015/jose@teste.com.br/124546
[HttpPost]
[Route("cadastrar/cliente/{nome}/{datanascimento}/{email}/{senha}")]
public HttpResponseMessage clienteCadastro(string nome,DateTime datanascimento,string email,string senha)
{
    try
    {
        var tCliente  = new ClienteAplicacao();
        tCliente.Inseri(nome,datanascimento,email,senha);
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Cadastro do cliente  " + nome + "  realizado.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex )
    {

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

na aplicação:

```
public void Inseri(string nome, DateTime datanascimento, string email, string senha)
{
    var strQuery = "";
    strQuery += "INSERT INTO CLIENTES (NOME, DATA_NASCIMENTO,EMAIL, SENHA)";
    strQuery += string.Format(" VALUES ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}' )", nome, datanascimento, email, senha);

    using (contexto = new Contexto())
    {
        contexto.ExecutaComando(strQuery);
    }
}
```

Comment: eu utilizo assim também.

Comment: Por acaso você está usando Entity Framework?

Comment: Não acredito que esta seja a melhor prática, imagina o tamanho da url quando você for passar 50 ou mais campos como parâmetro. Penso também que você não queira passar senha como texto puro. O correto é passar os valores por `JSON`, `XML`, etc e posteriormente deserializar .

Comment: @Randrade eu não estou usando Entity Framework

Comment: Acho que está dando para fazer SQL injection com esse seu código, outro ponto, nome de método até aonde eu sei, são verbos de ação... no seu caso seria INSERIR e não INSERI... mas é só um pequeno detalhe.

Comment: @PauloHDSousa , eu fiz a alteração do nome para INSERIR, você tem razão quanto ao SQL injection, mais a pessoa teria que saber o caminho exato para isso, como vou usar para celular então acho que fica mais complicado

Comment: Você não consegue mandar um JSON ou XML como o  @rubStackOverflow disse?

Answer (score 1):

Vamos lá,

Quando você tem uma requisição para persistir algo, você deve tomar alguns cuidados e adotar algumas boas práticas para evitar eventuais problemas. No caso de uma requisição `POST` para persistir algo, você pode muito bem enviar os dados no corpo da requisição, que existe justamente para isto. No lado do asp.net web api, você pode criar uma classe que faça o Binding destes dados e entregue um objeto pronto para você trabalhar, por exemplo.

```
public class ClienteDto
{
    public string Nome { get; set; },

    public DateTime DataNascimento { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Senha { get; set; }
}
```

Em seu método da API, você poderia receber um objeto deste tipo.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("cadastrar/cliente")]
public HttpResponseMessage clienteCadastro(ClientDto clienteDto)
{
    // passe o objeto DTO para a cada de negócios...

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);  
}
```

Lembre-se que ao fazer isto, você deve passar os dados no Body Request de sua requisição, sendo que isto poderia ser feito utilizando o formato `json`, por exemplo:

```
{
   Nome: "João",
   DataNascimento: "2000-01-05",
   Email: "email@test.com",
   Senha: "123456"
}
```

> Obs: Se puder encriptar a senha para trafegar isto em sua requisição,
>   é uma recomendação de segurança.

Chegando na camada que irá persistir, notei que em seu código ,você usa ADO.Net. Não há problemas nisto, no entanto, tenha cuidado com o que alguns colegas comentaram na sua questão, sobre SQL Injection. Dependendo da forma como você constroi uma instância de `IDbCommand` e adiciona parâmetros, você corre o risco de ter um comando indesejado sendo executado na sua base de dados. Você poderia tentar algo assim:

```
public void Inserir(ClientDto clienteDto)
{
    var strQuery = "@"INSERT INTO CLIENTES (NOME, DATA_NASCIMENTO,EMAIL, SENHA) VALUES (@nome, @datanascimento, @email, @senha)"

    using (var conexao = new Conexao())
    {
            var parametros = List<SqlParameter>();

            var nomeParametro = new SqlParameter("@nome", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            nomeParametro.Value = clienteDto.Nome;

            parametros.Add(nomeParametro)

            // adicione outros parametros nesta lista


            // implement uma sobrecarga que adicione os parametros ao seu Command neste método!
            contexto.ExecutaComando(strQuery, parametros);
    }   
}
```

Espero que ajude.